# Error connecting to mysql server on openshift

Tags: c#, mysql, openshift

Im trying to connect to a mysql database running on openshift.
The computer I have used is running win 10.
Below is my C# code snippet of what im trying to do. The server address, password, and username have been blanked out.

```
  string connStr = @"Server=xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com:3306;Database=hurnhusms;Uid=XXX;password=XXX;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successfull !");
            conn.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("error => " + ex.ToString()); 
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

when I run the application all I get is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
>   i have also ran rhc port-forward , i have also pinged the mysql port on the site and it is open.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: not sure about openshift, but make sure your database configured for connections from your external address

Comment: I think you're using the SqlServer connection objects.  If you're connecting to mysql then you should be using the library with the MySqlConnection.

Comment: @GaryHolland I have changed it over to MySqlConnection but i am still meet with " Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." i have tried both the ip and webaddress.

Comment: @mike .  Only suggestions I have.  Is it the Port.  You could remove this from the connection string (as 3306 is default) or add a seperate port=3306 line.  Also, do you have the MySQL connector for .net correctly installed on your machine.

Comment: @GaryHolland have have just reinstalled the connector and also tried the port still no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I figured out is that I need to execute the rhc port-forward  and then keep that window open (not terminate that command). I didn't realize that window need to stay open.